# What is the most efficient way to find the biggest linear independent subset of expressions

Tags: python, sympy

I have a list of expressions

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')

e0 = x
e1 = x**2
e2 = 2*x**2
```

how do I find the biggest subset of linear independent expressions?
You can assume the expressions to be ordered, i.e. an expression with a lower index is preferred.

I tried iterating the following:

```
a = numbered_symbols('a')
a0 = next(a)
a1 = next(a)
a2 = next(a)

solve(a0*e0 + a1*e1, a0, a1)
# {a0: 0, a1: 0}

solve(a0*e0 + a1*e1 + a2*e2, a0, a1, a2)
# {a1: -2*a2, a0: 0}
```

So I take e0 and e1. To automatize this:

```
from operator import mul
from toolz import take

def _linear_independent(exprs):
    c = list(take(len(exprs), numbered_symbols("c")))
    expr = sum(map(mul, exprs, c))
    res = solve(expr, c)
    return all(v == 0 for v in res.values())

def max_independent_set(exprs):
    max_set = [exprs[0]]
    for e in exprs[1:]:
        if _linear_independent(max_set + [e]):
            max_set.append(e)
    return max_set

max_independent_set([e0, e1, e2]) # [x, x**2]
```

Is there a more efficient (runtime) way to do this?
Currently, I need to call solve N-1 and the system to solve is increasing. Maybe one could break this down into smaller tasks?

Bonus: I am also looking for a way to do this with more than one independent variable. My current approach does not work (it solves not only for the coefficients):

```
x, y = symbols('x y')
e0 = x
e1 = y
exprs = [e0, e1]

c = list(take(len(exprs), numbered_symbols("c")))
expr = sum(map(mul, exprs, c))
res = solve(expr, c)  # [{c0: -c1*y/x}]
```

My expressions describe functions from R^N -> R. Previously I'd evaluate them on my data set and exclude based on correlation.

Comment: Three questions (please address in an [edit], if appropriate): 1) By *efficient* you are referring to runtime, right? 2) What’s the problem with more than one independent variable? 3) Do you have any useful a-priori knowledge about your input? All the approaches I can think of will have a hard time with inputs like `[x+y, y+z, x+2*y+z]`. If you could exclude such cases, I might have an answer for you.

Comment: I added more details about the problem. Ultimately, I'd like to do this with inputs like [x+y, y+z, x+2*y+z], but also [cos(x), cos(x)sin(y)] etc

Comment: `[cos(x), cos(x)sin(y)]` does not have any linear dependencies (according to my understanding of your question). Not even `[cos(x), cos(x)*sin(y), sin(y)]` does. The problem with `[x+y, y+z, x+2*y+z]` is that the addition that makes the linear dependency is not an explicit symbolic addition anymore (as it would be, e.g., in `[x+y+y+z]`, which SymPy automatically simplifies). Excluding such cases would make things considerably easier.

Comment: `[cos(x), cos(x)*sin(y)]` is linearly dependent if you consider `y` to be a constant, but not if you consider it to be a variable.

Comment: Every symbol `x, y, z` is meant to be a variable not a constant, so `[cos(x), cos(x)*sin(y)]` is not linear dependent. I want to use this in a context of symbolic regression, so I can't (and don't want to) exclude cases like `x+2*y+z`. Expressions can be any combination given a set of functions, operators, variables and constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer of asmeurer I came up with a solution.

Using the nullspace works great, but you'd still need to find the list of independent/atomic expressions:

```
import itertools as it
import operator
from functools import reduce
import sympy

def get_atomic(expr, normalize=True):
    if isinstance(expr, sympy.Mul):
        if isinstance(expr.args[0], sympy.Number):
            args_ = expr.args[1:]
        else:
            args_ = expr.args
        return reduce(operator.mul, args_)
    elif isinstance(expr, (sympy.Float, sympy.Integer)):
        return 1 if normalize else expr
    else:
        return expr

all_summands = ((get_atomic(s) for s in sympy.Add.make_args(e)) for e in exprs)
atomic = list(set(it.chain.from_iterable(all_summands)))
A, b = sympy.linear_eq_to_matrix(exprs, atomic)

redundant_indices = [np.where(sympy.matrix2numpy(nullvector) == 1) [0][-1]
                     for nullvector in A.T.nullspace()]

exprs_ = [e for i, e in enumerate(exprs) if i not in redundant_indices]
```

That works well for my testcases:

```
exprs = [x, x**2, x**3, x**3 - x**2]
# exprs_ = [x, x**2, x**3]
exprs = [cos(x), cos(x)*sin(y), sin(y)]
# exprs_ = [cos(x), cos(x)*sin(y), sin(y)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use some matrix routines to calculate this. The function `linear_eq_to_matrix` will convert a system of equations into a matrix:

```
>>> A, b = linear_eq_to_matrix([x, x**2, 2*x**2], [x, x**2])
>>> pprint(A)
⎡1  0⎤
⎢    ⎥
⎢0  1⎥
⎢    ⎥
⎣0  2⎦
```

(if you have constant factors those will be put in `b` as the right-hand side of the equation). This is the transpose of what you want, since the matrix operations you want work on columns. `A.T.columnspace` will return the columns that span the columns of `A.T`:

```
>>> A, b = linear_eq_to_matrix([x, x**2, 2*x**2], [x, x**2])
>>> pprint(A.T.columnspace())
⎡⎡1⎤  ⎡0⎤⎤
⎢⎢ ⎥, ⎢ ⎥⎥
⎣⎣0⎦  ⎣1⎦⎦
```

This tells you that the first and second elements span the space (since you got the first and second columns of `A.T`). If you also want to know how to rewrite the other elements in terms of those linearly independent elements, use `A.T.nullspace()`.

For instance:

```
>>> pprint(A.T.nullspace())
⎡⎡0 ⎤⎤
⎢⎢  ⎥⎥
⎢⎢-2⎥⎥
⎢⎢  ⎥⎥
⎣⎣1 ⎦⎦
```

This means that `-2*(x**2) + 1*(2*x**2) = 0` (so the last two elements are linearly independent.

To take a larger example:

```
>>> A, b = linear_eq_to_matrix([x, 2*x, x**2, 2*x**2, x**3, x + x**2], [x, x**2, x**3])
>>> pprint(A.T)
⎡1  2  0  0  0  1⎤
⎢                ⎥
⎢0  0  1  2  0  1⎥
⎢                ⎥
⎣0  0  0  0  1  0⎦
>>> pprint(A.T.columnspace())
⎡⎡1⎤  ⎡0⎤  ⎡0⎤⎤
⎢⎢ ⎥  ⎢ ⎥  ⎢ ⎥⎥
⎢⎢0⎥, ⎢1⎥, ⎢0⎥⎥
⎢⎢ ⎥  ⎢ ⎥  ⎢ ⎥⎥
⎣⎣0⎦  ⎣0⎦  ⎣1⎦⎦
>>> pprint(A.T.nullspace())
⎡⎡-2⎤  ⎡0 ⎤  ⎡-1⎤⎤
⎢⎢  ⎥  ⎢  ⎥  ⎢  ⎥⎥
⎢⎢1 ⎥  ⎢0 ⎥  ⎢0 ⎥⎥
⎢⎢  ⎥  ⎢  ⎥  ⎢  ⎥⎥
⎢⎢0 ⎥  ⎢-2⎥  ⎢-1⎥⎥
⎢⎢  ⎥, ⎢  ⎥, ⎢  ⎥⎥
⎢⎢0 ⎥  ⎢1 ⎥  ⎢0 ⎥⎥
⎢⎢  ⎥  ⎢  ⎥  ⎢  ⎥⎥
⎢⎢0 ⎥  ⎢0 ⎥  ⎢0 ⎥⎥
⎢⎢  ⎥  ⎢  ⎥  ⎢  ⎥⎥
⎣⎣0 ⎦  ⎣0 ⎦  ⎣1 ⎦⎦
```

Note that we have 3 spanning vectors of the nullspace and 3 spanning vectors of the column space, which matches the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) (3 + 3 = 6). For the columnspace, we got the first, second, and fifth column of `A.T`, meaning those are the linearly independent elements (alternately, we could just multiply the columns by our vector of terms that we extracted the matrix from, `Matrix([x, x**2, x**3]).T`.

In the nullspace, the final `1` in each column represents the element that can be removed, and the terms above it (actually their negation) tell you how to rewrite it in terms of the others (e.g., `2*x = -(-2)*x`, `2*x**2 = -(2)*x**2`, `x + x**2 = -(1)*x + -(1)*x**2`).

This does require that you start with a list of expressions that you are considering to be terms (in this example, `[x, x**2, x**3]`). This can matter. To take an example from the comments on your question, `[cos(x), cos(x)*sin(y)]` is linearly dependent if your terms are just `[cos(x)]`, but not even a linear system if your terms are `[cos(x), sin(y)]` (and a linearly independent linear system if they are `[cos(x), cos(x)*sin(y)]`.